# How to prevent SBT from trying to execute abstract classes with JUnit test methods?

Tags: scala, junit, sbt

I'm migrating a mixed Java/Scala project from Maven to SBT. When I run "test" I get lots of errors on classes that are abstract classes with JUnit test methods in them. They all have a name of the form Abstract*TestCase. Maven safely ignored these classes since their names don't start or end with the word Test and correctly executed their subclasses. How can I get SBT to behave the same way?

Comment: I think it just doesn't work, and you'll have to open a request for that to work. Here: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/issues/list.

Comment: Is that JUnit 3? If it's JUnit 4 you can just put @Ignore on top of the Abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

I raised a request for this behavior [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/issues/detail?id=146).